# Python - Spread **kwargs into a dictionary similar to ES6 spread

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that could receive an unexpected amount of additional arguments in addition to the expected and required arguments. I would like to pass the additional arguments into a dictionary along with the expected arguments. Is there a "spread" operator or similar method in Python similar to JavaScript's ES6 spread operator?

Version in JS

```
function track({ action, category, ...args }) {
  analytics.track(action, {
    category,
    ...args
  })
}
```

Version in Python

```py
def track(action, category, **kwargs):
    analytics.track(action, {
        'category': category,
        ...**kwargs # ???
    })
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're just looking for the `**` operator. In general, `{**a, **b}`, where `a` and `b` are `dicts`, creates a `dict` with the combined key-value pairs from `a` and `b`, with `b` taking precedence in case of key overlaps. An example:

```
def f(category, **kwargs):
    return {'category': category, **kwargs}

print(f('this_category', this='this', that='that'))
```

Output:

```
{'category': 'this_category', 'this': 'this', 'that': 'that'}
```

In your case, therefore, you probably want something like this:

```
analytics.track(action, {'category': category, **kwargs})
```